# How to prevent users from accessing Admin Page?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I want to prevent the users from accessing the admin url, i already secured the views but **/admin/** is still accessible .

**admin.py**

```
import os

from flask import request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

from flask_admin import Admin, AdminIndexView
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.contrib.fileadmin import FileAdmin

from flask_login import current_user,login_required

from develop.extentions import admin_permission

from wtforms import FileField

class AdminIndex(AdminIndexView):
    @expose('/admin/')
    def index(self):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
        return self.render('admin/home.html')

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.roles('admin')

class CustomModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and admin_permission.can
    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for('main.index', next=request.url))

class CustomFileView(FileAdmin):

    allowed_extensions = (
        'txt',
        'md',
        'js',
        'css',
        'html',
        'jpg',
        'gif',
        'png'
    )

    editable_extensions = ('md','html','js','css','txt')

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and admin_permission.can

class UserView(CustomModelView):
    column_list = ('username', 'confirmed','joined')

    column_searchable_list = ('username', 'id')
    column_filters = ('joined', 'email', 'username')

    path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__),
            os.pardir
        )
    )

    form_extra_fields = {
        "image": FileField('Image')
    }

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(__file__),
                os.pardir
            )
        )

        image_path = os.path.join(path, 'static', 'images')
        photo_data = request.files.get(form.image.name)

        if photo_data:
            name = secure_filename(photo_data.filename)
            model.image = '/static/images/' + name
            photo_data.save(os.path.join(image_path, name))
```

By this way, all my other views are hidden but i still accessing the admin page , please how to prevent unauthenticated user from even accessing the **admin** .

Comment: It's not clear to me, after reading your code here and your comment on @MrLeeh's answer, whether your attempt to use that code included the `@expose('/')`. Your above code doesn't include it. If you aren't decorating your index method, I'm assuming that the index method from the parent class (flask_admin.AdminIndexView.index) is still serving your `/admin/` endpoint.

Comment: code has been updated !

Comment: Given that the code above uses `@expose('/admin/')`, it's still not clear if you've tried using `@expose('/')`? Flask-admin is already prepending the `/admin/` to these endpoints, so I think your decorator above would be serving `/admin/admin/`.

Answer (score 0):

Handle your check for authentication in your `index` function and make a redirect if not authenticated.

```
@expose('/')
def index(self):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return self.render('admin/home.html')
```

Comment: I tried your code but without a val, it still accessible, i will provide the **admin.py** code so it will be more clear .

Comment: As @abathur stated: You need to use `@expose('/')`, not `@expose('/admin/')` for this to work.